# Probability of linear search with repeated elements.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, algorithms, searching

I am trying to find the probability that a linear search on an array of size n takes j comparisons. We are looking for the element x and there are k x's in the array where 0 < k < n. I tried looking at this as a conditional probability problem but I ended with an overly complicated factorial that I can't simplify and now I am stuck any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is $\binom{n - j}{k - 1} / \binom{n}{k}$. The number of ways the first position of $x$ is on the $j$th position divided by the total number of ways.